# how to use the row [a,b] to index another array as data[a:b]?

Tags: python, indexing, numpy

I have two arrays, the first one is a (n, 2) array which contains the start and the end of a selection in a data pool, the second one is the data pool.

The general idea is to use the first to extract the relevant data from the second but I don't see how to do it cleanly with numpy.

I found the following solution, but it looks clumsy :

```
relevant_data = datapool[np.arange(*selection[0])]]
```

Any idea ?

**update** :  The ability to nest indexing is a big plus (getting a subpart of selection).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `slice`:

```
In [1]: row = [4,7]

In [2]: data = range(10000)

In [3]: data[slice(*row)]
Out[3]: [4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: thank you, this is likely what I want. the slice notation allows to nest the indexing (getting a subpart of row), which will be useful in my case. I am still concerned about the cost of unpacking the row, but I don't see how to avoid it.

Answer (score 4):

An even simpler solution than using `slice()` is

```
row = [4, 7]
data[row[0]:row[1]]
```

which might be easier to read since it is a bit more explicit.

Comment: Thank you, i like the pythonic clarity but as said above the ability to sub-index the row is likely to be useful. Still, I will "timeit" the solutions to see if there are big perf differences.

Comment: @Lionel: Of course you could use `data[selection[index, 0]:selection[index, 1]]`.